# Android validation with edit text is not working?

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I'm new to android and making and app which required Edit Text and it's validation. I have tried  different ways to validate the edit text but is is not working. Please some help me in this, Thanks.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    EditText age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
    EditText weight= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);
    EditText height= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);


    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cal);

 calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             final String a=age.getText().toString();
             int aN=Integer.parseInt(a);
             final String w=weight.getText().toString();
             int wN=Integer.parseInt(w);
             final String h=height.getText().toString();
             int hN=Integer.parseInt(h);

             if(a.length()==0){
                 age.requestFocus();
                 age.setError("Between 13 ans 80");
             }
             if(w.length()==0){
                 weight.requestFocus();
                 weight.setError("Weight required!");
             }
             if(h.length()==0){
                 height.requestFocus();
                 height.setError("Height required!");
             }
            }
          });
```

Comment: Its better to provide what is issue in current code with question.

Comment: What is not working?? In which case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


             if(age.length()==0){
                 age.requestFocus();
                 age.setError("Between 13 ans 80");
             }
             else if(weight.length()==0){
                 weight.requestFocus();
                 weight.setError("Weight required!");
             }
             else if(height.length()==0){
                 height.requestFocus();
                 height.setError("Height required!");
             }

         else{
              a=age.getText().toString();
              aN=Integer.parseInt(a);
              w=weight.getText().toString();
              wN=Integer.parseInt(w);
              h=height.getText().toString();
             hN=Integer.parseInt(h);

             }
            }
          });
```

With your initial code it will give a `NumberFormat Exception` if the editTexts are left blank.I dont know what is a,w,h in your code but i guess you mistakenly assumed your edittexts as a,w,h which is evidently **age,weight and height** respectively.

**UPDATE**

Declare the Strings and the integer variables ASSOCIATED WITH THIS CODE globally i.e. before onCreate().Like String a,w,h and int aN,wN,hN.

Comment: a,w,h are strings which holds the value of edit texts age, weight and height. I tried your code but it's asking for creating the local varables for aN,wN and hN.

Comment: then create the local variables before oncreate like int an,wn,hn.Then it should work.

Comment: still giving redline error with a,w,h cannot be resolved

Comment: before oncreate create three string variables and 3 integer variables like String a,w,h and int an,wn,hn.Then use a=age.getText().toString();
aN=Integer.parseInt(a); inside your button.

Comment: thanks @kgandroid.. just declared everything globally, now its working... :):)

Comment: what if we want add some range. for eg: age between 13 to 80 if it's exceeds the range then gives error.

Comment: aN=Integer.parseInt(a);if(a>=13 && a<=80){your code}

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
         if(TextUtils.isEmpty(a)){
             age.requestFocus();
             age.setError("Between 13 ans 80");
         }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try your code like this

```
 EditText age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
 EditText weight= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);
 EditText height= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);

 age.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
 weight.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
 height.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
 Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cal);

  calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

         String a=age.getText().toString().trim();
         String w=weight.getText().toString().trim();
         String h=height.getText().toString().trim();

         if(TextUtils.isEmpty(a)){
           age.requestFocus();
           age.setError("Between 13 ans 80");
         }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(w)){
             weight.requestFocus();
             weight.setError("Weight required!");
         }
         if(TextUtils.isEmpty(h)){
             height.requestFocus();
             height.setError("Height required!");
         }
         int aN=Integer.parseInt(a);
         int wN=Integer.parseInt(w);
         int hN=Integer.parseInt(h);
        }
      });
```

DOC :[TextUtils.isEmpty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: If the edittexts are left blank then this code will generate exception if user try to use Integer.parseInt();

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty() method return true if edittext null or 0 size and i am not parsing anything so it will not generate exception and see DOC link in my answer @kgandroid

Comment: but before using TextUtils.isEmpty() you are using   String a=age.getText().toString().trim();Now if user writes int aN=Integer.parseInt(a); immidiately next line and if age is blank then what will be the outcome??

Comment: but if edittext blank than  setError() method will throw error not going to int aN=Integer.parseInt(a); step

Comment: seterror() method is firing after using getText().Watch the code carefully.

Comment: @kgandroid in my code i am not parsing any thing and isEmpty() method prevents blank edittext so no chance to generate exception end of this 3 condition if user wants than he/she can covert string to int after 3 condition

Comment: You are not parsing anything but the asker of this question is using Integer.parseInt().Your code is ok.But if I try to use the former immediately after the getText() then it will generate numberformat exception(for blank edittext).